# Can't Able to access the Header View in Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I added a header view in the TableView, but I can't able to access that view or any subview of Header view in the `IBAction` method.

**My Code is as follow:**

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *header_View=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 40)];
    header_View.tag=section;
    UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn.Frame=header_View.bounds;
    [btn setTitle:[arr_headerTitles objectAtIndex:section] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.titleLabel.font=FontChampagneLimousinesBold(18);
    btn.tag=section;
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(expandTableHeaderView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIImageView *img_arrow=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 05, 15, 15)];
    img_arrow.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_white_down.png"];

    [header_View addSubview:btn];
    [header_View addSubview:img_arrow];
    return header_View;
}

-(void)expandTableHeaderView:(UIButton*)sender{
     //  UIView* _header_view =(UIView*)[_tbl viewWithTag:[sender tag]]; //Also tried
        UIView *_header_view=[_tbl headerViewForSection:section]; //shows nil;

        UIView *view = (UIView *)[_header_view viewWithTag:[sender tag]];
}
```

**Help me to solve this**
**Thank you**

Comment: can you add one offset of the tag? for example define int offset = 500; when header_View.tag = offset+section; then in the action [_tbl viewWithTag:(offset + section)]

Comment: please check your tableview delegate connection

Comment: is your headerview appeared in tableview?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
-(void)expandTableHeaderView:(UIButton*)sender{
    UIView *_header_view =  sender.superview;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using **UITableViewHeaderFooterView** instead of **UIView** while creating the header_View, seems working

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header_View=[[UITableViewHeaderFooterView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 40)];
    header_View.tag=section;
    UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn.Frame=header_View.bounds;
    [btn setTitle:[arr_headerTitles objectAtIndex:section] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.titleLabel.font=FontChampagneLimousinesBold(18);
    btn.tag=section;
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(expandTableHeaderView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIImageView *img_arrow=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 05, 15, 15)];
    img_arrow.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_white_down.png"];

    [header_View addSubview:btn];
    [header_View addSubview:img_arrow];
    return header_View;
}

-(void)expandTableHeaderView:(UIButton*)sender{
     //  UIView* _header_view =(UIView*)[_tbl viewWithTag:[sender tag]]; //Also tried
        UITableViewHeaderFooterView *_header_view=[_tbl headerViewForSection:sender.tag]; //shows nil;

        UIView *view = (UIView *)[_header_view viewWithTag:[sender tag]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your header height is not defined.
Try this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
   return 40.0;//the height of your header view
}
```

This might work.

And please put breakpoint marker in your IBAction method to see if its working or not.